# Laravel Collections - Results order

Tags: php, laravel, collections, sql-order-by

The following....

Controller:

```
public function treatmentsList()
    {
        $treatments = Treatment::with('category')->where('status', 1)->orderBy('medical_name')->get();
        $groups = $treatments->groupBy('category.name');
        return view('pages.treatments.list', compact( 'groups'));
    }
```

View:

```
<ul>
    @foreach($groups as $category_name => $treatments)
        <li>
            <h4>{{ $category_name }}</h4>
            <ul>
                @foreach($treatments as $treatment)
                    <li>
                        <h5>{{ $treatment->medical_name }}</h5>
                    </li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

Gives me...

The treatments grouped in their categories and in alphabetical order but the categories are not in alphabetical order.

```
- Category B
Treatment A
Treatment B
Treatment C

- Category A
Treatment A
Treatment B

- Category C
Treatment A
Treatment B
Treatment C
Treatment D
```

How can I get the treatments and categories both listed in alphabetical order?

Comment: Have you tried an `->orderBy('category.name')` after the groupBy function call?

Comment: adding `->orderBy('category.name')` after the groupBy gives me: Method orderBy does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this by adding query constraints for the eager loading query:

```
Treatment::with(['category' => function ($query) { 
    $query->orderBy('name');
}])
->where('status', 1)
->orderBy('medical_name')
->get();
```

Hi,

I'm not sure if this is what you mean... but it did not worked... I still get the categories not alphabetically listed.

```
public function treatmentsList()
{
    $treatments = Treatment::with(['category' => function ($query) {
        $query->orderBy('name');
    }])
        ->where('status', 1)
        ->orderBy('medical_name')
        ->get();
    $groups = $treatments->groupBy('category.name');
    return view('pages.treatments.listA', compact( 'groups'));
}
```

You're right - my mistake. I think that answer is the join query:

```
public function treatmentsList()
{
    $treatments = Treatment::with('category')
        ->select('treatment.*')
        ->join('category', 'category.id', '=', 'treatment.category_id')
        ->where('treatment.status', 1)
        ->orderBy('category.name')
        ->orderBy('treatment.medical_name')
        ->get();
    $groups = $treatments->groupBy('category.name');
    return view('pages.treatments.listA', compact( 'groups'));
}
```

Check the names of tables and fields from above example. This should work.

Comment: Thank you so much... I just adjusted the tables names and all is working.